# Inconsistent handling of URI

Tags: safari, zsh, macos

I have a script that contains these two lines:

```
open https://ldsgenealogy.com/10-Free-Useful-Websites-for-US-Genealogy-Research.htm
open https://UniGen.us
```

Every time I invoke this script, another tab opens for UniGen.us, but ldsgenealogy.com only gets one tab the first time.  (Safari)

Why would this be, and is there a way to have UniGen not get multiple tabs?

Comment: Might be worth it to include the whole script or at least essential parts of it that could affect the two lines given. We cannot tell much about your problem with only those two lines.

Comment: There is nothing else in the script that has anything to do with websites.  It deals with local files.  The first websites are used to find genealogical information to put into local files.  The second is a website I maintain with some of that information.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't including another "open xxx" later?

Comment: The first line opens *and* activates a new browser window (assuming browser isn’t active at this time). Since it’s active when the second line is called, it opens a new tab. Which behavior would you prefer?

Comment: If the script is invoked without the browser active, there would of course be two tabs.  But when it is invoked again, the LDS tab is not duplicated but the UniGen tab is.  And if there were another "open UniGen" in the script (there isn't), there would probably be two tabs for each call instead of one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the system goes through these steps after an `open 'the_uri'` call:

- If the browser isn't running, launch it and open `the_uri`.
- Otherwise, search through open tabs.
- If there is a tab with `the_uri`, use that tab.
- If there is not a tab with `the_uri`, open that URI in a new tab.

For the first URI, Safari is able to find a URI that matches `https://ldsgenealogy.com/ ...`, so it simply switches to that tab on later calls.

But the UniGen URI is always redirected. A call to `https://UniGen.us` opens a tab with `https://unigen.us/tree/HHH`. Therefore in a subsequent call to open `UniGen.us`, Safari is unable to find a match to that exact URI, so it opens a new tab.

This is based on a limited set of tests; you can try some other URIs to see if the pattern holds.

One workaround is to simply use the final URI with `open https://unigen.us/tree/HHH`. This should work just fine if the redirect always goes to the same place.

Comment: This explanation certainly fits the symptoms.  So I installed the suggested fix, and it worked.